# sox segmentation fault

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault, sox

My attempt to record sound with sox on Raspberry PI fails:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ rec new.wav
Segmentation fault
```

And so does play:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ play test.wav
Segmentation fault
```

Yet it will convert files for me:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ sox message.wav message.flac rate 16k
pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ mplayer message.flac
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.32.2
AUDIO: 16000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 160.0 kbit/31.26% (ratio: 20004->64000)
Selected audio codec: [ffflac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg FLAC audio)
==========================================================================
```

The debug information don't seem to provide a whole lot of info:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ sox -V5 -d new.wav
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_amr_nb_format_fn': library 0x1af6308, entry point 0x4038f2c8
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_amr_wb_format_fn': library 0x1af6a80, entry point 0x4000ee10
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_ao_format_fn': library 0x1af71e0, entry point 0x4003ebb8
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_ffmpeg_format_fn': library 0x1af7918, entry point 0x403de914
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_flac_format_fn': library 0x1afe1e0, entry point 0x419f70a8
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_gsm_format_fn': library 0x1b0e570, entry point 0x403e8cf4
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_lpc10_format_fn': library 0x1b0e978, entry point 0x41a5dcc4
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_mp3_format_fn': library 0x1b0ed80, entry point 0x41a6bd1c
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_oss_format_fn': library 0x1b0fb00, entry point 0x41a77d74
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_pulseaudio_format_fn': library 0x1b0ff70, entry point 0x41ac9a80
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_sndfile_format_fn': library 0x1b153f8, entry point 0x41e98ec0
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_vorbis_format_fn': library 0x1b15830, entry point 0x41ad49ec
sox DBUG formats: opening format plugin `lsx_wavpack_format_fn': library 0x1b15c68, entry point 0x41ea57c8
sox INFO oss: OSS driver only supports bytes and words
sox INFO oss: Forcing to signed linear word
Segmentation fault
```

Here is some version data that might be helpful:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ sox --version
sox:      SoX v14.4.0

pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ cat ~/.asoundrc
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:2,0"
        }
    capture.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
        }
}

pi@raspberrypi ~/tmp $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #250 PREEMPT Thu Oct 18 19:03:02 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this SoX based on the Debian package? Because the problem very much looks like [Debian bug #676167](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=676167) that was introduced in version 14.4.0-3 and fixed in 14.4.0-5.

It also appears (from the list of format plugins) that you don’t have the `libsox-fmt-alsa` package installed, but you’ll need it for ALSA playback.

So, you should install `libsox-fmt-alsa` and either upgrade the `sox` package to at least 14.4.0-5, or set the environment variable `AUDIODRIVER=alsa` for a workaround.